# Why isn't there enough time to change our opinion?

Tags: discussion, voting, grace-period

I can't remove a vote I made on an answer because 'I last voted 6 min ago'. Do you think this is enough time? people always change their opinion about things, there should be a longer time for rethinking the vote.

Comment: Related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5120/, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/420/cant-change-your-vote-after-an-hour?noredirect=1&lq=1,

Comment: How long would you like it?  6 minutes?  6 hours?  6 days?

Answer (score 12):

Yes, I think it is enough time. You should make up your mind first and vote only then. If you cannot make up your mind, do not vote.

Note also that if the post should change, then you could in fact change your vote.

Comment: *Three* users object to the notion of making up one's mind before acting? Wow.

Comment: @Did, probably the same people who will jump into a pool with both feet.

Comment: @J.M. To be fair how do you jump into a pool with only one foot?

Comment: @Najib: If you only have one foot, there is no problem. If you have both feet, amputate one of them, without loss of generality remove your left foot. If you don't have any feet, first put on your prosthetic feet, thus reducing the problem to the case where you have both feet. So without loss of generality we may assume that you have only one foot, now jump into a pool.

Comment: @Did: If only the grace period was long enough, they might have changed their vote!

Comment: Dear @Did / quid : Sarcasm aside now, of course we all want people to think before they act, but I think the point here is rather that people can think both before and after they've committed to a position. It does not seem unreasonable to me at all that within 5-10 minutes of committing one way, one might suddenly think of reasons to retract or reverse a vote. But given how easy it is to jostle the question loose again to change votes, it is not that serious of a problem...

Comment: @rschwieb there can be scenarios where one might legitimately want to change a vote later on, but It is not clear to me that extending the period, say, to 10 minutes would help much. In the other direction, I do think that the period should stay short enough to send the message that the voting decision is rather a final one (barring changes to the post), and not a tentative one. Tentative and more generally careless voting (not only up/down, also close/open) is in my opinion already enough of a problem on the site. I see no reason to add to it.

Comment: That said, if somebody has a particular reason why, say, 10 mins would be much preferable to 5, likely I would not be opposed to that change.

Comment: I'm wondering if there should be no time limit for a vote change after an edit on a question/answer. There could be a situation where you vote on a question/answer, it is edited a lot later, you don't immediately notice the edit but later come back and see it.

Comment: @user236182 An edit unlocks the votes cast before the edit and they stay unlocked indefinitely. If I understand you correctly, what you propose is the current situation.